# why not work <size android:width="30dp"/> command

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 

  <corners    
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>

  <padding android:left="15dp"/>

  <size android:width="30dp"/> 

</shape>
```

I tried: size android:width="30dp","60dp","90dp"....end sp end px   nothing works

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"?

Comment: don't you miss the height parameter, too?

Comment: Which kind of shape do you want to define? Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: The length of a shape not be smaller